# Not receiving APNS messages from Azure after upgrade to Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, azure, apple-push-notifications, swift3

After updating my application to Swift 3 (what an experience that was! ) - I knew I had to rework the Notification code due to the changes in iOS10.

Using this helpful resource - I was able to recode and I am getting a valid connection

https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/Notifications10Swift/blob/master/Notifications10Swift/AppDelegate.swift

I also amended the Capabilties for the project, adding 1) Notifications, and 2) Background Modes / Remote Notifications.

**However, when I send a test message thru the Azure 'test-send' feature, I don't receive it.**

Here's the relevant code from my AppDelegate:

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Register for remote notifications
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
{ 
    let hub: SBNotificationHub = SBNotificationHub.init(connectionString: APISettings.Instance.notificationHubEndpoint, notificationHubPath: APISettings.Instance.notificationHubName)

    hub.registerNative(withDeviceToken: deviceToken, tags: nil) { (error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil){
            print("Error registering for notifications: %@", error)
        } else {
            print("Registration ok")
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Error = ",error.localizedDescription)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
}

// MARK: UNUserNotificationCenter Delegate // >= iOS 10

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("User Info = ",notification.request.content.userInfo)
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("User Info = ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable Keychain access in Capabilities ?

Comment: Thanks for responding - yes, KeyChain is enabled

Comment: Can you try setting the priority of the push notification sent from the azure to high

Answer (score -1):

**Try to call this function on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and clean >Run your app**

func registerNotification()

{

UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

if application.respondsToSelector(#selector(UIApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(_:)))

{

```
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)


        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    }

}
```

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

```
    if notificationSettings.types != .None {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this attempts to resolve the issue. Please elaborate.